# GitHub Branch Protection Rules - disable "Require Approvals"

Tags: github, git-branch, pull-request

Something has changed on GitHub's branch protection rules page recently (?).

**Require approvals** is always enabled (in checked state). Is there any way to disable it? Previously, I'm pretty sure this was possible. Now it's confusing, especially since the description says "When enabled, ...", suggesting that there is a way to disable it.

[image]

Comment: It looks like as of today (Nov 5 2021), the checkbox is no longer disabled, and can now be unchecked without devtools.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

At this time of writing, there seems to be no point for this checkbox to be disabled, because its state *does* seem to influence the repository settings. It feels like the UI changes to the Branch protection rule page are still a work in progress.

### Trick using Dev Tools

You can enable it using your browsers Developer tools and removing the `disabled="disabled"` attribute of the `<input>` element, at which point you may uncheck the checkbox.

The dropdown for the required number of approval now disappears.

[image]

Once you uncheck it and subsequently save your Branch protection rule, it will reset the required amount of approvals to **zero**, even though the checkbox resets to its disabled state.

[image]

At this point you don't need any approvals to merge into the protected branch.

[image]

This trick allows small teams or single developers to continue using Pull Requests to organize their workflow, without enforcing PR approvals.

Comment: wow... nice tip!

Comment: Yes, nice tip, and probably the best solution until GitHub fixes their UI.

Comment: This behavior has been fixed.
You can now uncheck the box to have branch protected without required approvals.